# How do you import something in appDelegate.m(Objective-C) into a Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wrote an iOS app in Swift, then it is required by my company for my project to import one of Alibaba's SDK, which is written in Objective-C. There's [a doc](http://baichuan.taobao.com/doc2/detail.htm?spm=a3c0d.7629140.0.0.j4y0Va&treeId=51&articleId=102860&docType=1) about how to do it in Chinese.

In the demo, it seems all codes needed for the SDK to run is written in `appDelegate.m` in Obj-C. I've read about Obj-C/Swift bridging header and stuff, but I don't know how to make it work for this case.

I can't imagine having 2 version of appDelegate in one app, how should I do it?

By the way, this is the code they expect me to copy paste into AppDelegate.m:

```
[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] setDebugLogOpen:YES];
[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] setUseTaobaoNativeDetail:NO];
[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] setViewType:ALBB_ITEM_VIEWTYPE_TAOBAO];
[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] setISVCode:@"my_isv_code"];

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options 
{     
    BOOL isHandledByALBBSDK=[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url];
    BOOL isHandledByALBBSDK=[[ALBBSDK sharedInstance] handleOpenURL:url];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Just use the Swift delegate and translate the code Alibaba code to Swift. When integrating Alibaba into an Obj-C app, you are not creating a second app delegate either.

Comment: Are you required to use the Obj-C app delegate as the app delegate of your Swift app?  Or are you required to use only some functionality from the Obj-C delegate, but your Swift app has to have a delegate with functionality different from that of the Ojb-C one?  Are you allowed to translate Obj-C to Swift, or do you have to use Obj-C, period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, I translate every Obj-C code into Swift and put everything into AppDelegate.swift. It is easy than I thought with auto completion, and it works just fine.